# the c*-algebra generated by a closed ideal and a c*-subalgebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

If $\mathscr{A}$ is an unital c*-algebra, $I$ is a closed ideal of $\mathscr{A}$ ,and $\mathscr{B}$ is a unital c*-subalgebra of $\mathscr{A}$ .

Show that the c*-algebra generated by $I\cup\mathscr{B}$ is $I+\mathscr{B}$.

I know that it only need to prove that  $I+\mathscr{B}$ is closed, however I do not know how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is enough to consider the quotient $A\to A/I$.

Comment: @AliBagheri  can you expalin this more clear ? thank you

Comment: Please look at Theorem 3.1.7 (C*-algebra and operator theory by Murphy)